# Foreign Key Cross-Reference Between Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design, schema

I'm a beginner to database design.  So I have two tables for implementing multiple choice, one called `MC`, for holding the questions, and `MC_choice`, for holding the choices for each question.  So `MC_choice` has a foreign key constrained to reference to `MC`.  So far, so good.

In my 1st iteration, I stored the correct choice in the `MC_choice` table with a Boolean column.  And then I thought, hmm, there's some redundancy and potential update anomalies, and since which choice is correct is functionally dependent on the question itself, I'm going to store the correct choice in the `MC` table itself.

So I added a field in the `MC` table that is a foreign key constrained to pointing to `MC_choice`.  But now it becomes very difficult to insert new choices or questions because the two are now like recursively constrained.  I am using Rails and being a beginner in that as well I feel like this schema design is making my life quite unnecessarily difficult.

1) If I want to insist on this recursive foreign key reference, how do I save to the database?
2) Does this design make sense?  I feel like the functional dependency argues for it, but seems so cumbersome in practice.
3) Does ActiveRecord in Rails support this kind of operation?
4) If the above schema is just silly, how should I be designing my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing "functionally dependent". That applies to column sets within one table. You mean that the correct answer for a question is a function of the question.

The situation is indeed only "like" "recursive". There is a cycle in the FK table referencing. But this does not *define* the FKs in terms of each other, so there's no recursion. We can say that the two tables are mutually  or simultaneously constrained. Or more clearly that some constraint constrains both tables. (Which can be expressed as the conjunction of two FK constraints.)

Your situations can be described by tables and simple row membership criteria something like this:

```
Question(qid,text) -- question [qid] has text [text]
    key qid
Answer(aid,text) -- answer [aid] has text [text]
    key aid
Offers(qid,aid) -- question [qid] offers answer [aid]
    key (qid,aid)
    fk qid to Question, fk aid to Answer
Ok(qid,aid) -- [aid] is the right answer to [qid]
    key (qid,aid)
    fk (qid,aid) to Offers
    fk qid to Question, fk aid to Answer
```

This is a straightforward design. It happens that there are no FK cycles. (Also the FKs to Question and Answer do not need to be declared/explicit because they are consequences of the FK to Offers and its FKs.)

One can combine these in various ways. You have chosen something (that has FK cycles) like:

```
MC(qid,text,aid)
    -- question [qid] has answer [aid]
    AND [aid] is the right answer to [qid]
MC_choice(aid,qid,text)
    -- question [qid] offers answer [aid]
    AND answer [aid] has text [text])
```

Because the AND of tables' membership criteria is the membership criterion for the NATURAL JOIN of the tables,

```
MC = Question NATURAL JOIN Ok
MC_choice = Offers NATURAL JOIN Answer
```

> 1) If I want to insist on this recursive foreign key reference, how do I save to the database?

In SQL if a declared FK subrow has some columns NULL (there are other modes re this) then the DBMS considers the constraint satisfied. So allow MC aid to be nullable. First insert an MC qid with NULL aid, then insert the qid and aid into MC_choice, then change the MC NULL to the qid's MC_choice aid.

But in typical SQL DBMSs you can't have FK cycles. (For no good reason.) If you mean you want those columns in those tables anyway, then you can drop a FK declaration but add triggers. SQL DBMSs offer only a handful of declarative constraint forms; in general one must also use triggers to express constraints.

> 2) Does this design make sense? I feel like the functional dependency argues for it, but seems so cumbersome in practice.

It is cumbersome, but the fact that a correct answer is a function of its question does not mean that answers have to be in any particular table with their questions.

> 3) Does ActiveRecord in Rails support this kind of operation?

Yes. Make the MC model (table) aid field (column) nullable.

> 4) If the above schema is just silly, how should I be designing my tables?

There's some ground between not best and silly, ie cumbersome does not imply silly, but just use the above design, or this variant:

```
MC = Question
MC_choice = Offers NATURAL JOIN Answer
MC_ok = Ok
```

Always try to identify the simplest table *predicates* (membership criteria, sentence templates, fill-in-the-[named-]blank statements) that you can for describing your situations. You may want to collect several into one table, but there may be more than one choice for where a functional relationship goes.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Learned a lot from just going through and thinking it through.  Would give you more than just 1 upvote if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to keep multiple choice questions and the answers for them in the database, I would probably do something like this:

```
tblQuestions
------------
Question_Id (pk)
Question_Text
Question_Correct_Answer (nullable, fk to tblAnswers)

tblAnswers
----------
Answer_Id (pk)
Answer_Question_Id (fk to tblQuestion)
Answer_Text
```

When inserting a new question, insert it with `null` in the `Question_Correct_Answer` column, and populate it when inserting the answers to the question.
The insert of question and it's answers should be inside a single transaction, so that it's impossible to insert a question without it's answers and it's correct answer id.

For keeping the answers the user choose, you only need to keep the answer id 
(since every answer belongs only to a single question).

Add a view to select both the question text and the answer text to display the results, something like this:

```
select question_text, 
       answer_text, 
       case when answer_Id = question_correct_answer then
         1
       else
         0
       end as IsCorrect
from tblUserAnswer
inner join tblAnswer ON(UserAnswer_Answer_Id = Answer_Id)
inner join tblQuestion  ON(Answer_Question_Id = Question_Id)
```